# VBA Format function is showing "Could not load some objects because they are not available on this machine"

Tags: excel, vba

I am about to work on an "older" program of a colleague. Testing it, I get an error message in the following line: (`Format` being marked)

```
Me.ComboBoxDistribution.AddItem Format(1#, "#,##0.00")
```

Error message is in german. I give my best translating it:

> An object could not be loaded because it is not available on this computer

As if it wasn't enough the next error message is following:

> Error while compiling: Project or library not found.

Is the `Format` Function just included in older Excel Versions? How can I fix this error? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your code works fine on my version of Excel (o365 2016). Is this in a userform or in the sheet?

Comment: @Tom That's strange as I'm using the same version. It's in a Userform. It makes a difference?

Comment: I think it may be 2016 doesn't have some of the form components library. It's not the code line. it's the lack of a components library

Comment: No that's how I set it up - worked fine. It may be an invalid reference library. Check if you've got any 'missing' in your references

Comment: @Tom I don't know exactly what you mean with invalid reference librabry.

Comment: VBA Console -> Tools -> References. That will list all the references in the project. Make sure there aren't any missing

Comment: @J.schmidt Just a note: The tag [tag:basic] is not really relevant for [tag:vba] questions.

Comment: Oh ok! Dankeschön!

Comment: Side question: What does `1#` mean? Whats the difference to `1`?